# Find/estimate original resolution of image

Tags: image-processing

The size of the following screenshot is 482 x 547 pixels, but it's really just a screenshot of something with a lot lower resolution:

[image]

The metadata of the original image is not available.

Is there a way to programmatically estimate the original resolution of the image? How?

(If this question isn't suitable to s/o, please suggest an alternative site on the stackexchange network.)

Comment: The transitions all happen at fixed locations. The distance between these transitions is always a multiple of the original pixel size. Find the shortest distance between transitions.

Comment: pick a language! we're on SO after all. -- for pixel art, working with edge/gradient info is the best bet. I'd sum absolute gradients, form profiles from that, and fourier that to get the "frequency" (peak in spectrum), which will be robust to noise. -- direct fourier transforms would work on smoothly resampled data (e.g. a lazy DVD to HD upscale still only has enough bandwidth to fill a DVD frame)

Comment: Note that one of the white shapes on the red hat of the mushroom appears to be misaligned by half-a-pixel vertically with respect to the rest of the picture; because of this white shape, a non-robust "exact" algorithm would be forced to multiply the resolution by two; would this be the desired behaviour? i.e. the whole image appears to be 26 pixels in height, but because of this half-pixel misalignment, the algorithm would be forced to say the image is really 52 pixels in height.

Comment: @Stef Yep, it'd need to be 52 pixels.

Comment: @NicoSchlömer Ok, and is the big image's dimension guaranteed to be an exact multiple of the number of pixels? If so, that would reduce the possibilities so much that a bruteforce approach becomes very realistic. EDIT: Well, I can answer my own question. 482 and 547 don't have common divisors except 1.

Comment: @Stef No. It really is a screenshot; the alignment could be off, too.